# Extending CKEditor with multiple plugins

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I want to include more features and plugins to the default CKEditor included in Drupal 8. 
I found an article explaining how to do so here

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creation-extended-functionality-basic-ckeditor-drupal-aleksey-razumov

In the article a module is created to include that specific plugin however I would like to know if there's a way to include multiple plugins from one module. For example I would like to create a module called 'CKEditor Advanced Style' that includes multiple CKEditor plugins rather than having a module for layout, a module for tables, and so on.